# How to combine with_dict and with_sequence?

Tags: grep, ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to check if a JBoss management user has already been created. I have a **working play**:

```
- name: Check if Management user has already been created
  shell: "grep -i '{{jbossvars.mgmt_user}}' {{env_home}}/standalone/configuration/mgmt-users.properties | grep -v '#'"
  register: mgmt_users_file
  changed_when: false
  failed_when: mgmt_users_file.rc != 1 and mgmt_users_file.rc != 0
- name: Add Management user if it has not been created
  shell: "{{env_home}}/bin/add-user.sh --silent=true {{jbossvars.mgmt_user}} {{jbossvars.mgmt_pass}}"
  when: mgmt_users_file.stdout == ""
```

Now I'm **trying to loop** over a dict while maintaining the same functionality
The script can only be executed if mgmt_users_file.results[X].stdout (with X being the index) is empty.

I was thinking of

```
- name: Add Management user if it has not been created
  shell: "{{ item.value['env_home'] }}/bin/add-user.sh --silent=true {{ item.value['mgmt_user'] }} {{ item.value['mgmt_pass'] }}"
  when: mgmt_users_file.results[{{item2}}].stdout == ""
  with_dict: "{{jbossvars_extra.environments}}"
  with_sequence:
    start=0
    end={{jbossvars_extra.environments|count}}
```

Actually, I just need to be able to nest 2 loops (*item* and *item2*)

How can I obtain this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to concatenate the name of the variable this way

```
mgmt_users_file_{{ item.value['env_home'] }}.stdout == ""
```

Use the register the same way as before

```
register: mgmt_users_file
```

print *mgmt_users_file* to see what structure the loop created

```
- debug: var=mgmt_users_file
```

Use the structure of *mgmt_users_file* in the next loop.

Comment: Yes, I already came to that conclusion. Unfortunately, I didn't succeed in doing so.
The variables I need are mgmt_users_file.results[0].stdout, mgmt_users_file.results[1].stdout, ... etc.

I was looking for a possibility to use an increment variable to use as index for mgmt_users_file.results withing the with_dict. This doesn't seem to exist. Any ideas?

Something like this:
`- name: task
  shell: "script.sh"
  when: mgmt_users_file.results[X].stdout == ""
  with_dict: "{{jbossvars_extra.environments}}"`

With "X" being the incrementable variable.

Comment: Post the data in the question and show the result you want to achieve. Make it minimal.

Comment: I did my best trying to clarify the issue. @VladimirBotka

Comment: Take a look at [Convert list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56755332/convert-list-of-objects-string-string-into-dictionary-string-liststring/) as an example of how it looks like when someone "did his best trying to clarify the issue". And this was his 1st question!

Comment: I could try, but it's just not as simple as the one you're referring to. I'm starting to realize that Ansible might not be able to fulfill my requirements. Anyhow, thanks for your help on this question and the others!