# Convert list of objects (string, string) into Dictionary (string, list<string>) in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a list of objects (each object contains two attributes of type string) which I need to convert into Dictionary. The first attribute of the object will become a key, the second attribute of the object would have to be combined into a list of strings.

I went through several solutions but couldn't find exactly what I need.

**Input Example:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "AAA",
        "value": "111"
    },
    {
        "name": "AAA",
        "value": "222"
    },
    {
        "name": "BBB",
        "value": "333"
    },
    {
        "name": "BBB",
        "value": "444"
    },
    {
        "name": "CCC",
        "value": "555"
    }
]
```

**Desired Outputs (either one works):**

```
[
    {
        "name": "AAA",
        "value": [ "111", "222" ]
    },
    {
        "name": "BBB",
        "value": [ "333", "444" ]
    },
    {
        "name": "CCC",
        "value": [ "555" ]
    }
]
```

```
[
    "AAA": [ "111", "222" ],
    "BBB": [ "333", "444" ],
    "CCC": [ "555" ]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    my_list: "{{ my_list|default([]) +
                 [{item.0: item.1|json_query('[].value')}] }}"
  loop: "{{ input|groupby('name') }}"
- debug:
    var: my_list
```

give

```
"my_list": [
    {
        "AAA": [
            "111", 
            "222"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "BBB": [
            "333", 
            "444"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "CCC": [
            "555"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you. This works great and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach the problem. The solution is mainly based on the use of the [`json_query` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter)

First, you need a list of all unique names in the list of objects so you can loop over it and extract the corresponding values. This is done by filtering the `input` variable with the following jinja2 template expresion `{{ input | json_query("[].name") | unique }}`

Now we just have to loop over that list and filter the `input` variable again. This time we want to extract a flat list of all values for all objects having the given name. This is done with the following example jinja2 expression: `{{ input | json_query("[?name=='a_unique_name'].value") }}`

The rest is just a matter of setting facts correctly, either in a new list or hashmap as your requested. I made both in the following example playbook.

Note: I used yaml folded blocks with white space control (`>-`) in this example to ease writing (limiting quotes escaping...) and reading (long lines split...). If you are not familiar with them you can check https://yaml-multiline.info/ for a complete overview of all options.

The playbook

```
---
- name: Rearrange var example
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

     input: [
      { "name": "AAA", "value": "111" },
      { "name": "AAA", "value": "222" },
      { "name": "BBB", "value": "333" },
      { "name": "BBB", "value": "444" },
      { "name": "CCC", "value": "555" }
     ]

  tasks:

    - name: Create list and dict vars
      vars:
        jsquery: >-
          [?name=='{{ item }}'].value
      set_fact:
        list_var: >-
          {{
            list_var | default([])
            +
            [{'name': item, 'value': input | json_query(jsquery)}]
          }}
        dict_var: >-
          {{
            dict_var | default({})
            | combine ({ item: input | json_query(jsquery)})
          }}
      loop: "{{ input | json_query('[].name') | unique }}"


    - name: Show calculated list and dict vars
      debug:
        var: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - list_var
        - dict_var
```

Which gives:

```
PLAY [Rearrange var example]  ************************************************

TASK [Create list and dict vars] *********************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=AAA)
ok: [localhost] => (item=BBB)
ok: [localhost] => (item=CCC)

TASK [Show calculated vars] **************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=list_var) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "list_var",
    "list_var": [
        {
            "name": "AAA",
            "value": [
                "111",
                "222"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "BBB",
            "value": [
                "333",
                "444"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "CCC",
            "value": [
                "555"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=dict_var) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "dict_var": {
        "AAA": [
            "111",
            "222"
        ],
        "BBB": [
            "333",
            "444"
        ],
        "CCC": [
            "555"
        ]
    },
    "item": "dict_var"
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you. I did actually try to attempt to do it your way by first parsing out unique key attributes, which it worked. Second part with jinja2 expression is something I couldn't figure out.